# Allow webdriver browser to popup on desktop from Windows 10 Service

Tags: selenium, batch-file, windows-services

So my understanding is that from Windows Vista, they have disabled windows service to interact with desktop, but I was just wondering if there was a workaround that would fit my needs

So, I have 4 different Selenium Grids running on Jenkins agents and one desktop that will run nodes. And when pipeline starts, it will send a Http call with its grid ip address in the body to a node server that is running as a windows service.

```
POST {windows_service_node_server}/startnode
```

When the windows service server receives request, it will start a node and connect the hub to the corresponding Jenkins selenium Grid by running a batchfile that has

```
java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver.exe -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.8.1.jar -role node -hub http://{jenkins_hub_address}:4444/grid/register -nodeConfig nodeConfig.json
```

The problem is that all the selenium tests run in the background with no browser in the foreground.

This is perfectly fine, but I'd like to actually see the browser instance popup if possible.

If I run the server not as a windows service, it will launch the browser on the foreground and work fine.

Has anyone have any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the Article about [Interactive Services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/services/interactive-services) by Microsoft:

> Services cannot directly interact with a user as of Windows Vista. Therefore, the techniques mentioned in the section titled Using an Interactive Service should not be used in new code.

If you want to test your setup, you can start grid nodes while logged on. If you want to see the system under test, you can get remote screenshots. If you need monitoring, there are tools to inspect running processes on remote machines.

But letting services that are designed to run unattended interact with the screen is simply a bad idea so the windows developers prevent this technically.